# Postgres undefined column in trigger

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-trigger

I receive an error when inserting a row in Orderlist for this trigger:

```
ERROR:  column "qty_in_stock" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT qty_in_stock > 0
           ^
QUERY:  SELECT qty_in_stock > 0
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function books_upd() line 6 at CASE
****** Error **********

ERROR: column "qty_in_stock" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Context: PL/pgSQL function books_upd() line 6 at CASE
```

Here is my code:

```
INSERT INTO orderlist VALUES (12,1235,6)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION books_upd()
RETURNS trigger as $bookupd$
BEGIN
UPDATE books
SET qty_in_stock=qty_in_stock - NEW.quantity
WHERE isbn=NEW.isbn;
CASE WHEN qty_in_stock > 0 THEN
UPDATE stockmanager
set quantity=quantity+NEW.quantity
WHERE isbn=NEW.isbn;
END CASE;   

RETURN NEW;
END;
$bookupd$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Many forum suggestions for putting quote marks around qty_in_stock - same error.

Table info:

Table books: ""isbn""-pk
""title"" 
""author""
""qty_in_stock""
""price""
""cost""
""year-published""
""publisherid""

Table stockmanager:
""isbn""-pk,fk
""quantity""

Any helps appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a CASE statement like that and you can't reference a table's column outside of a SQL statement. What you need to do is to store the new value in a variable and then use that with an `if` statement:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION books_upd()
  RETURNS trigger as 
$bookupd$
DECLARE 
  l_qty integer;
BEGIN
  UPDATE books
    SET qty_in_stock = qty_in_stock - NEW.quantity
  WHERE isbn=NEW.isbn
  RETURNING qty_in_stock INTO l_qty;

  if l_qty > 0 THEN
    UPDATE stockmanager
       set quantity= quantity + NEW.quantity
    WHERE isbn = NEW.isbn;
  END IF;   

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$bookupd$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```